# Calculate probability of bird in the cage

Tags: probability

I have a problem in Probability. Below is the question:-

You found a black cage which has only one sparrow. The sparrow is either red or blue in color. Another sparrow, which is blue in color, is thrown into the cage. Now you open the door of the cage and let one bird fly. The sparrow which came out happens to be blue.

What is the probability of finding another Blue Sparrow in the cage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the color of the first sparrow are equally likely, and that the birds are equally likely to escape, you have four options of equal likelihood:

- Original bird (Red) escapes. Remaining is (Blue)
- Original bird (Blue) escapes. Remaining is (Blue)
- New bird (Blue) escapes. Remaining is (Red)
- New bird (Blue) escapes. Remaining is (Blue)

Only the three latter options have a blue bird escaping, so the chance or finding another blue bird in the cage is 2/3.